# Security for ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a .net based application which is for a financial institution and it has multiple roles so I am not using built in ROLE PROVIDER.

Now what i want is that when create user i just assign role and when user logs in with the assigned role he/she cannot open any form on which he/she has no rights.

How to come up with a role based security system for my application ? I would appreciate if someone can help me and guide me to come up with a strong and secure application.

Thanks

Comment: @user239684 "so I am not using built in ROLE PROVIDER" ? why not?

Comment: Thanks for the links. I am a little confused do i need to implement the following? 1. Create role master table 2. create role detail table and add userids belongs to this role. 3. create a detail form and select role from combo and assign form names 4. on page load of every form i need to query table and check if user is allowed to use this form or not???

Comment: I suggest to use the regular ASP.NET membership providers. They handle roles most sufficiently. There is no point of implementing your own solution, unless you know, what you do and need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to take a look at the Membership API.

This blog post from Scott Guthrie has links to several resources to help you get started.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/asp.net-2.0-membership_2c00_-roles_2c00_-forms-authentication_2c00_-and-security-resources-.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Read the following article:

[Introduction to Role-Based Security in .NET](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/security/article.php/c7415)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I am a little confused do i need to implement the following?
1. Create role master table
2. create role detail table and add userids belongs to this role.
3. create a detail form and select role from combo and assign form names
4. on page load of every form i need to query table and check if user is allowed to use this form or not???

Answer (score 1):

If the links posted in the other answer are too many to start with, try reading that article from MS: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301390.aspx